# Best practices with large amount of data

Tags: database-design

I'm building a solution and I have a question.

All my data is currently stored in a unique table. Each row of data is associated with a type.

My question is, what's the best practice for defining a table structure: all data in an unique table with associated type or data stored in dedicated type table?

eg: how to store people and associated colors.

- all data in an unique table like `id`, `people_id`, `color_id`
- data stored in table dedicated to color:

  - table `blue`: `id`, `people_id`
  - table `red` : `id`, `people_id`

In my opinion, it's better to have everything in a single table to avoid complex queries, but I'm scared about query time with billions of rows.

Comment: When looking at this think about the amount of changes that will need to be done if a new color is added or removed. With the first method you will just need to update two tables. However with the second method you would have to create an entire new table or drop a table to remove the color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 common contemporary database designs:

1) Most database design is based on [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), so have a look at that.

2) When that has performance problems [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) is a common route.

3) When **vast** amounts of data are projected database design has moved away from these techniques (1 and 2 are two sides of the same coin) and new technologies have been used, for example have a look at [noSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

Unless you are dealing with seriously vast amounts of data you'll probably want to start with 1) and possibly look at 2) if and when you have performance issues.

"Everything in a single table" is generally a bad idea as that table becomes huge, with a great deal of contention on it - every part of the application using it constantly. This would lead to deadlocks, for example, making queries slow.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the first option otherwise you will be changing your database every time you want to add a new color.  It would be a nightmare.

Also, if you ever needed to select for multiple colors you would have to join to the various tables, which isn't terrible, but is needlessly complex.

If you are using SQL Server, [you might look at partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx) and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

modern sql databases should handle such large tables, where you got all data in one. and its faster than doing `joins` on a huge data sets.

tip: maybe you might want to take a look at graph databases which don't have problems with duplicate data (like the color which will be repeated across rows)

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [database normalization](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878), this will help you to achieve best practices for YOUR specific situation (a few simple steps make it much easier).

As a side note, in terms of performance, more tables is usually better as you end up loading a lower number of tuples, but this can make query writing more complex. You should start by normalizing and creating a strong relational integrity and only then worry about performance concerns.

Comment: "*more tables is usually better..*" is a gross oversimplification that easily leads beginners to create horribly non-relational designs (like the second one the OP proposed).  Let them figure out Normalization first.  Only when they understand that completely should they start to worry about the performance of the *design* (as opposed to the performance of the implementation, which is a different thing).

Comment: I said **in terms of performance** and that much is fairly true, if you have fourteen tables for user data, each one storing different parts of a user's data that should all be in one table, you will probably improve performance, **but, as I also said** you will make query writing an awful lot more difficult. I think when taken holistically my answer is pretty accurate, though of course if you take a quote out of context it will seem wrong.

Comment: You present Normalization and Performance as co-equal and independent things in database design.  They are neither.  The first step in good design is *always* Normalization, because that's how you make sure that it's a *correct* design.  Not coincidentally, the first step in Performance is *also* a normalized design.  The number of tables has nothing material to do with either of these until much later in the process.  Worrying about the number of tables during the design process is a recipe for bad designs, *especially* for someone who is unsure of what they are doing.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - can see why you'd think that, though it wasn't the message I was trying to put across. Edited the post to make clear my intention.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Comment: A properly indexed table containing six different types of entities will perform just as well as six separate tables (one per entity), so I'm not sure why you think more tables = better performance. Number of tables very rarely has anything to do with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say from here, all depends on what sort of queries you are doing. If you put everything in one table and there are a lot of changes, optimising your indexes will be a big thing, if you split them up aside from having more complex code, something will have to 'know' blue is in blue table, then  optimising joins will be.

Personally I'd start with option one, and see if your indexes get too big / too messy to deal with. The other way looks like premature optimisation to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a people table and a color table as base tables.  And then a people-color table that links people with their color.  This design is very flexible and extensible.  If you have performance issues with queries later on, then you can consider a denormalized version ofthe person-color table to address performance.